# PostgreSQL- query a raster by XY

Tags: postgis, raster, gdal, postgresql, raster2pgsql

Windows 10, PostgreSQL 11

I successfully managed to export a .tif raster into PostgreSQL using raster2pgsql:

```
raster2pgsql -s 27700 -I -C -M -Y "D:\Data_Location\country.tif" -F -t 50x50 public.country_rast | psql -U username -d dbname -h hostaddress -p 5432
```

Now I'd like to query the raster using a function which takes an XY coordinate and returns the value of the raster cell it intersects.

I use this:

```
SELECT ST_VALUE (rast,1,(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(319006 212230)',27700))) 
FROM public.country_rast
```

However the query returns ALL 1 million rows of the raster, wheras I only want the value that the given XY intersects. How can I do this?

Comment: @Taras I think that's unrelated. It doesn't do anything but throw a syntax error.

Comment: I am not sure if this will help, but remove the parenthesis around ST_GeomFromText. Otherwise I can't see anything wrong with your approach

Comment: @JohnPowell I'm afraid that makes no difference at all.

Comment: OK, I have run similar queries many times, and can't see anything wrong. Are you able to share the tif?

Comment: @JohnPowell sure. here is a sample of it (i still have the same issues with this sample as with the main tif) https://we.tl/t-rsRT17wMwo
upload that in the way I have and let me know what you find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ST_VALUE (rast,1,(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(319006 212230)',27700))) 
FROM public.country_rast
WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, ST_GeomFromText('POINT(319006 212230)',27700))
```